# Find max int among 1000 integers, use bubble sort or merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Bubble sort is O(n) at best, O(n^2) at worst, and its memory usage is O(1) . Merge sort is always O(n log n), but its memory usage is O(n). Explain which algorithm you would use to implement a function that takes an array of integers and returns the max integer in the collection, assuming that the length of the array is less than 1000. What if the array length is greater than 1000?

Comment: finding or sorting? it isn't the same thing...

Comment: nobody is going to make your homework for you, you must show some effort

Comment: If this is an exercise for some kind of school, I'd suggest to quit, because it's extremely stupid. You don't need to sort AT ALL to find the maximum. Just iterate through everything and remember the highest value. Time O(n), Memory O(1)

Comment: Actually, there is an in-place merge sort that's O(n log n). It has a (very) large constant, but asymptotically, it's O(n log n). Search for "in place merge sort." Like others, I'm wondering why you'd use a sorting algorithm to find just the largest item.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest could be to traverse the array and keep track of the largest one as you move. This takes `O(N)` time. So you dont need to use any sorting algorithm also.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.

Just loop through the items and keep track of the largest value that you find. That is an O(n) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is `O(n2)` **on average**, i.e. it's rarely, if ever, a good idea to use it.

Merge-sort is always `O(n log n)`.

So, between those 2 choices, merge-sort is preferable.

There are also [plenty of other choices for sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). And [some dedicated to numeric data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Distribution_sort).

However, to just find the maximum element, there is no need to sort, you can simply iterate through the integers and keep track of the maximum.

Comment: 1000 elements worth of data is nothing. `O(n log n)` versus `O(n ^ 2)` doesn't matter unless you are using a computer from the '80s.

Comment: @H2CO3 True, but if this is homework or an interview, suggesting bubble-sort probably isn't a good idea, unless we're talking about something like 10 elements (and, since most, if not all, library sorts use O(n log n) sorts, why use a (presumably self-implemented) O(n^2) one at all).

Comment: sure, I'm not saying that "let's go ahead and suggest the use of bubble sort for production code". I don't like wasting resources for no reason. This is a different scenario, though -- if I were a programming teacher teaching a beginner class, I wouldn't classify the use of bubble sort as "wrong", **not even as "inefficient"** -- we should teach beginners what happens in real life. That is, let's not do premature optimization, instead do a good job optimizing when necessary.